# ¿Es posible obtener un entero desde int *x?

Tags: c, punteros, parametros, números-enteros

busco una manera de solucionar este problema. Tengo una funcion llamada encolar que recibe como parámetros:

```
int extraer(pila *S, int *x)
```

Lo que hace es guardar el valor extraído de una pila en el segundo parámetro, es decir, "int *x". El problema es que después necesito ese valor como entero "int x" para ingresarlo como parámetro a esta función:

```
insertar(pila *S, int x)
```

No encuentro la manera de obtener un entero a partir de *x. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Es posible obtener un entero desde int *x?

Si el puntero apunta hacia al valor, solo es cuestión de [desreferenciar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_de_desreferencia) el puntero.

```
int a = 10;
int *b = &a;

printf("%d\n",*(b));
```

De esta manera obtienes el valor al que apunta, y no el valor que almacena el puntero (la dirección de memoria).